# Does rsync behave differently if it detects that a mount point is from a network instead of a local/external drive?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, rsync

Note: I don't think I did a good job of explaining what I was looking for.  The problem I'm running into is NOT which files rsync is selecting to mirror.  The problem is that rsync is taking WAY longer mirroring those same files.

To put it another way, before the VM was involved, the same set of files would get mirrored in no more than 20 minutes, regardless of if the destination was empty or not.  Other copy methods still work very quickly.  I'm trying to understand why rsync is so negatively affected when nothing else is.  Is it turning on extra analysis, encryption, compression, or other process-heavy things just because it thinks it's pulling from across a network when it's really not?  If so, is there any way for me to turn those off?

---

***Edit 1***: I removed the SSD from the equation and just used rsync to mirror the files from the VM guest to the host filesystem, and it's *still* extremely slow.

---

***Edit 2***: I found a few mentions elsewhere online that rsync across SMB shares can be slow, which is how MacOS does it's file sharing.  Instead, I turned on SSH and pointed rsync at the user@host:/path/to/data as the source.  In doing that, the full 400GB mirror took about 40 minutes.  It's still twice as long as the original 20 minutes, but *much* better than way over 3 hours.

---

I've been using rsync to mirror about 400GB of data to an external Thunderbolt 3 SSD.  It's a mix of some really big files and tons of super small files, and it syncs about 325GB each time it runs, but because of the drive speed, it only took about 15 minutes to do so.  The command I've been using is this:

`rsync -ahPmW --verbose --delete /my/local/directory /my/external/drive/`

I recently made a change to my environment and now have that data inside of a virtual machine that runs the same OS (MacOS Ventura) as the host.  The VM is on the local drive, with the VM directory containing the data mounted in the host file system.

When running the above `rsync` command to mirror the data from the VM share to the external SSD, it now takes *3+ hours* instead of 15 minutes, and I don't understand why.  I think it may have something to do with the fact that the data directory is now a mount point that is technically seen as being hosted on a different machine across a network.  While I do expect a bit of a slowdown due to the virtualization, that much of a time difference seems extreme.

I also think this is somehow related to `rsync` specifically because other copy methods work much more quickly.  For example, if I use `cp` instead, it can still copy the whole data set in about 30 minutes.  Or if I open both the external SSD and the mounted VM share in separate file browser windows, I can drag-and-drop the largest file (~320GB) in either direction and it will complete in about 10-15 minutes.

Because it may matter, here are details of my setup:

Host machine: MacOS Ventura

VM: MacOS Ventura

VM Software: VirtualBuddy (via Apple's virtualization subsystem, I think)

File Sharing: In the VM, I have file sharing turned on for the data directory.  The host can see that share on the "network" and mount it locally.  All file systems, including the external drive, are APFS volumes.

I feel like since all of this is still happening on a single computer, a lot of the normal suggestions to speed up `rsync` across networks, like turning on compression, shouldn't really apply here.  Is there any way I can get `rsync` to speed back up with the current setup?  I'd really prefer to use `rsync` to do my backups because it allows me to very easily control things like how many versions I keep, how old I let those versions get, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Im not an expert but I wonder if the way you are mounting the filesystem is not preserving the atime? - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/630228/rsync-keep-access-time-atime-how

Comment: I don't think the atime is the problem.  It's copying the correct files, which is everything that's been created or updated since the last time it was run.  It's just taking way longer to copy using rsync than other methods.

Comment: Add the `-i` flag (and remove `-W`). For each transferred file you'll now get a set of flags showing the reason for the copy/transfer. Does that help? If not, amend your question with example results and ping me a comment so I know to look again

Comment: Add another level of verbose, `-vv` to see all files considered and perhaps which are slowing down the comparision. Full info with `--debug=all4`.

Comment: @roaima and meuh: Like I said to davidgo, the problem is not which files are getting selected.  I know what's getting selected and I know why, and I can attest that rsync is selecting the correct files.  The problem is that the amount of time it's taking to mirror those files out of the VM is WAY longer than was did before the VM was being used.

Comment: Oh, and if you really can transfer files between two separate systems please include the command you're using. There may be potential optimisations there that we can spot

Comment: @roaima The command I'm using is in my post.  I did what you and meuh suggested and replaced -W with -i and added -vv, but it's a LOT of output.  The text file I redirected it to is right around 300MB.  It varies by about 5MB depending on if I use the mounted file share as a source or if I go the SSH route as a source.  Since I can't post that here, is there something in particular I should be looking for?

Comment: I'd start with just the single `-v`. If that doesn't help identify the issue then ramp up to the two